# Java vs C# and volatile 64 bit types (long, double)

Tags: java, c#, 64-bit, volatile

Java guarantees atomic read/writes to volatile declared long and doubles (even in a 32 bit environment), whereas C# does not (compile error). Why is it that C# does not support this, and does Java handle this on the bytecode level?

Comment: What compiler error are you talking about?

Comment: e.g. A volatile field cannot be of the type 'long'

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it that C# does not support this?

If you're running a 64bit system with a 64bit CLR version, [`long` and `double` reads and writes are guaranteed to be atomic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx):

> if you are running C# code on a 64 bit operating system in a 64 bit
>   version of the CLR then reads and writes of 64 bit doubles and long
>   integers are also guaranteed to be atomic

This is according to the [CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), section §I.12.6.6:

> A conforming CLI shall guarantee that **read and write access to
>   properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size
>   (the size of type native int) is atomic (see §I.12.6.2) when all the
>   write accesses to a location are the same size.** Atomic writes shall
>   alter no bits other than those written. Unless explicit layout control
>   (see Partition II (Controlling Instance Layout)) is used to alter the
>   default behavior, data elements no larger than the natural word size
>   (the size of a native int) shall be properly aligned. Object
>   references shall be treated as though they are stored in the native
>   word size.

Comment: Yes, but if we cannot mark it volatile we still got visibility problems. Java solves both problems even with 32 bit architecture.

Comment: What do you mean by *visibility problems*?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Stig I know what volatile is. I don't understand what you mean by its visibility.

Comment: Okay, read here http://jpbempel.blogspot.dk/2013/05/volatile-and-memory-barriers.html where the term visibility is used.